# Is this area safe and good for tourists in Paris?

Tags: accommodation, paris

We are going for some days to Paris. We have a hostel in this area:

> 45 rue du Docteur Babinski, 75018 Paris, France

Do you think it is safe? And is it an area where tourists normal book?

Moreover, is it an area where people from specific origin live? for example in my city we have some areas for Chinese people, some areas for African people, some areas for expats, some areas for local people.

What kind of area is that? And the most important thing if it is safe?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: IMO as it is written the question is opinion based. Please rephrase the question so that it does not ask for people's "opinion". Safety may mean different things to different people - e.g. I might feel unsafe in an area dominated by a particular ethnicity while another person might consider an area unsafe only if a spate of muggings has happened there.

Answer (score 3):

I used to live not far from there. It is a multi-ethnic area, right at the limit between Paris and the northern suburb of Saint-Ouen. It is safe enough, although tourists in Paris, even (and especially) in the poshest areas need to be aware of their surroundings at all times...

Your main problem will be noise, mostly. The Ibis is right in front of the Boulevard périphérique, a circular motorway that surrounds Paris. Rooms facing the Boulevard will be quite noisy.